# What does word 'shed' mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

**A lot of companies are shedding jobs**

Does it mean that companies intentionally get rid of jobs or that they lose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear. A company can certainly shed jobs intentionally, as in [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shed):

> : to rid oneself of temporarily or permanently as superfluous or unwanted
> // shed her inhibitions
> // the company shed 100 jobs

However, it can also shed things unintentionally, as suggested by [this headline](https://www.economist.com/business/netflix-sheds-subscribers-and-170bn-in-market-value/21808847):

> Netflix sheds subscribers—and $170bn in market value
> Can it tempt viewers back with advertising?

That being said, it is somewhat unusual for a company to lose jobs unintentionally. Workers can quit, but then we would usually say that the company "lost employees", not that it "shed jobs". Therefore, in this case it is likely that the companies eliminated the jobs intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

Shed has a few meanings, one of which is

> to get rid of something that is not wanted or is no longer necessary

In this case, "shedding jobs" actually fits this description, e.g.

> The company shed a further 250 jobs this month.

So yes, the companies are *intentionally* getting rid of jobs as they are no longer wanted or no longer necessary

Read shed definition at [this dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shed_1.) with examples